# How can i run a batch file hiddenly using shell script?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am working on shell script/ .vbs extension file, and I want to run a batch file hiddenly or in background from shell script. I am mentioning my code but its not executing a batch file. I have saved my file with a name `test.vbs`.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject()
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\RE.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`, not `CreateObject()`:

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\RE.bat" & Chr(34), 0
```

Otherwise VBScript wouldn't know what you want to create! So it can't know you want the shell object that has the `Run` method...

Answer (score 2):

when you write `CreateObject()`, you have to mention in those circle brackets. Your code looks fine just add `WScript.shell` in circle brackets like this.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
```